# Proper Hibernate Layer Design

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, concurrency

Im developing a java web application using hibernate and I came across a basic problem:

- Given user A triggers some Hibernate transaction. Start transaction, load, commit transaction.
- At the same time, user B triggers a similar transaction. Then, the will get an exception: *nested transactions not supported*.

It seems that no more than one transaction can be active at one time.

I researched for a solution and found a lot of overview explainations like transaction-per-session pattern, but nothing tangible.

So my **question** is: What is a proper and simple way to handle hibernate transactions for multiple concurrent users?

Comment: Hibernate is of course perfectly capable of handling simulatenous transactions :) Show us the exception you got, and the code that triggers it. There is no 'typical' use of hibernate as it will depend on what you use to handle your transactions.

Answer (score -1):

the transaction management is quite standard, just remember any exceptions thrown by Hibernate are fatal , you have to roll back the transaction and close the current session immediately.

You have to close the each and every transaction.

```
Session session = null;
Transaction t = null;
try{
   session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   t = session.beginTransaction();


   //do what ever you want(session);

   t.commit();


}catch(RuntimeException e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}
```